# Custom TableViewCells showing up differently when static and dynamic

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufMyd.png) is my custom static Table View.

The layout is:

```
- Table View (grey background)
    - Table View Section
        - Table View Cell (default background)
            - Content View (grey background)
                - View (white background)
                    - Label
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFn7o.png) is my custom dynamic Table View.

The layout is:

```
- Table View (grey background)
        - Table View Cell (default background)
            - Content View (grey background)
                - View (white background)
```

Both of these were created in Storyboard.

The aim of the game is to get the dynamic one looking like the static one (I'll sort out the fonts later). As you can see, the dynamic one currently 'overflows' with white in each direction leaving only the corners the desired grey colour.

Here is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for my dynamic Table View. Let me know if you need more code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;

}
```

**Update**

After adding the Autolayout constraints suggested in the comments below, my dynamic view now looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/855Db.png).

Comment: Did you set AutoLayout constraints on the dynamic layout? It looks like you need to set leading and trailing constraint on the view with white background. Also, is not there a difference between the two with one being Plain tableView and the other Grouped?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Both of the Table Views are Plain, so no difference there. When I tried to set constraints on the dynamic layout I found the options were greyed out.

Comment: You need to have AutoLayout enabled. For me the best way to make constraints is to control-drag in the object outline on the left side of the Interface Builder. Control-drag from white View to it's container, hold shift and select leading and trailing, then enter. You can then edit constraints in attribute inspector, like 20 points offset. Also it looks like you need to check the horizontal constraints too.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the left and right sides (take a look at my updated screenshot). Any idea how to do the same with the horizontal constraints?

Comment: It looks like that the white stripe in the middle is either the cell background itself or the tableview. Try to change background colors of each object in the tree to determine which one is it. You can then set its background to clear. Also double check the grey color of the container view.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look and it was a background colour issue even though this was the first thing I checked! If you think it's worth typing up an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Just typed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use make sure to enable AutoLayout and then set leading and trailing constraints of the white view to it's container.

For me the best way to make constraints is to control-drag in the object outline on the left side of the Interface Builder. Control-drag from white View to it's container, hold shift and select leading and trailing, then enter. You can then edit constraints in attribute inspector, like 20 points offset.

For the vertical white stripe in the middle it is either the cell background itself or the tableview. Try to change background colors of each object in the tree to determine which one is it. You can then set its background to clear.